# Djnago Template - Url with multiple parameter

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django template. I want to add multiple parameter in URL

currently I am passing only one parameter

my reset_password.html

```
Click on this link to reset your password 
{% if htmlVersion %}
    <div>
        <a href="{{domain}}{% url 'pweuser:user_password_sms_reset' token  %}">
            {{domain}}{% url 'pweuser:user_password_sms_reset' token %} 
        </a>
    </div>
{% else %}
{{domain}}{% url 'pweuser:user_password_sms_reset' token %}
{% endif %}
This link will expire in 15 minutes
```

my urls.py

```
url(r"^resetPasswordSms/(?P<token>[-\w_=]{28})/$", PasswordResetSmsView.as_view(), name="user_password_sms_reset",),
```

my views.py

```
    t = loader.get_template("reset_password.html")
    c = {"htmlVersion": True, "domain": settings.SITE_DOMAIN, "token": token.token}
    htmlVersion = t.render(c)
    c = {"htmlVersion": False, "domain": settings.SITE_DOMAIN, "token": token.token}
    textVersion = t.render(c)
```

Here its is working good

in this I want to add more than 1 parameter. means here token is the 1st parameter and I need to add userId as 2nd parameter and need to pass in  template..

how can i add multiple parameter in URL and template URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can add multiple parameters in URL:

```
from django.urls import re_path
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r"^resetPasswordSms/(?P<userId>[0-9])/(?P<token>[-\w_=]{28})/$", PasswordResetSmsView.as_view(), name="user_password_sms_reset")
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions

and template URL:

```
{% url 'pweuser:user_password_sms_reset' token=value1 userId=value2   %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

If you have any questions about any part, you can refer to the link below that.